# Create an apk on button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is it possible to generate an apk on button click?
I have an apk installed on the device(Original.apk)..For example.,Activity1 is shown which has a next button.On clicking next button, it goes to Activity2 which has button named "generate". On clicking this generate button, my app should create an apk that has only activity2 screen(as Generated.apk).i.e my device should contain a new apk apart from the existing one. (original.apk and Generated.apk)

Can any one please clear this doubt?? Is this scenario possible??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible. For this scenario to work, your Android device should have  ADT and JDK :). Android devices have only [DVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) or [ART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime). What an alternative approach you may follow:

1. If you have fixed number of APK, try to first create and put them in your asset folder. And try to retrieve the needed APK on button click.
2. If the APK file needs to be created dynamically, dedicate this task to a remote server. And your application should request the server (passing the required parameters) The remote server prepares the APK using its build tool.